# iOS NSManagedObject Data <fault> while deleting

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, fault

I am having some difficulties in deleting an entry from `Core Data`.

It works but the NSManagedObject data has no values (fault), and so sometimes the wrong entry will be deleted.

In my **deleteWholeDatabase** method the objects are filled with values.
And in the **deleteEntryFromDatabase** method are no values. But why?

Here are my methods:

```
-(NSArray*)databaseRequest{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:currentEntity inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return items;
}

-(void)deleteWholeDatabase{
    for (NSManagedObject *objectToDelete in [self databaseRequest]) {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:objectToDelete];
        NSLog(@"%@ object deleted",objectToDelete);
    }
    [self saveContext];
    NSLog(@"All entries deleted!");
}

-(void)deleteEntryFromDatabase:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context forEntry:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    NSManagedObject *objectToDelete=[[self databaseRequest] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[managedObjectContext objectWithID:[objectToDelete objectID]]];
    [self saveContext];
    NSLog(@"%@ deleted!",[managedObjectContext objectWithID:[objectToDelete objectID]]);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening.  Are items not getting deleted? Is the app crashing?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: There is no crash. an entry will be deleted, but sometimes the wrong

Comment: As @Luke said below, this is because the items returned from `[self databaseRequest]`, can be returned in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong entry is being deleted because each request return the itens in a different order. Try deleting the intens by comparing their memory adress

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping a calling `[self databaseRequest]` everywhere, I would keep a local copy of `NSManagedObjectID's` as an array.

```
- (void)init {
    self.entities = [self databaseRequest];
}

-(NSArray*)databaseRequest{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:currentEntity inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *itemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[items count]];
    for (NSManangedObject *item in items) {
        [itemIDs addObject:[item objectID]];
    }

    return items;
}
```

Then everywhere where you call `[self databaseRequest]`, you will get an have the correct `NSManagedObjectID`.  Then you just need to get the correct entity from the ID.